# Parity wallet not broadcasting

Tags: parity, pending-transactions

I'm having problem with Parity wallet. I've been trying to use it for ICO's as I can set the block number before hand.

I did try to buy BAT-tokens. I accidentally sent some before the block when it started. And it didn't go through, it went to the blockchain and gave this " Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad instruction] "

After that I set up the it to go through on the right block and set 3 000 000 gas. When the block came, it didn't go to the blockchain and it says "pending". All the other transfers are also "pending" and don't show up in etherscan. I'm loosing my patience with parity. What's wrong?

I was able to receive, but it wont broadcast.

Thank you in advance.

Johan

Comment: Check the block explorer , all BAT Token transaction are failing

Comment: The blockchain is full. For 5-6 hours now.

Answer (score 2):

There was an incredible amount of network usage during the BAT token sale and it is taking far longer than normal for transactions to propagate. Your local parity client simply begins propagating the transaction on the block you specify, but there is no telling how long until another node decides to mine it (assuming you aren't mining yourself). You can see how many nodes the transaction has been sent to by looking at the local TXQueue Viewer app that comes with Parity.